# What is the definition of a `service` in microservice/Service-oriented architecture?

Tags: microservices, services

I looking for the scientific agreed upon definition of 'service' in  Microservice/Service-oriented architecture.

I found a the definition

> - It logically represents a repeatable business activity with a    specified outcome.
> - It is self-contained.
> - It is a black box for its  consumers, meaning the consumer does not have to be aware of the service's inner workings.
> - It may be composed of other services.

[this source](https://web.archive.org/web/20160819141303/http://opengroup.org/soa/source-book/soa/soa.htm) which is hardly 'scientific agreed upon' in the sense it is on the internet.

From an understanding standpoint this can be grasp easily, but is there more precise, contextual definition. Who defined defined it? Where does one services start and where does it end? what principles are used to define a services? Surely, abstractly how can we formulate it in a definition?

Comment: You won't find a scientific definition for this. What code people group into one service is 100% arbitrary, not constrained by anything. Its not like there is a hard reference like a gravitational constant or a speed of light.

Comment: This question presumes that there is a scientific agreed upon definition, this may not be the case for all terms. Even if there is an original well defined meaning, there is a risk that the actual usage starts to drift until it can mean completely different things for different people.

Comment: Note that the bullet points are just the usual programming principles (in order: models a specific problem, isolation & separation of concerns, encapsulation & a well-defined API, composition) that can be applied in other contexts (e.g. OOP). It's the distribution strategy that's different. Stop thinking about this as people following prescribed rules; it's people building on more general principles and each other's work to create a new representation of the problem domain. Just how a new scientific model (or a math theory, for that matter) will *make up* new definitions. *That's* modeling.

Comment: So, abstractly, it's a small [precise meaning of "small" unspecified] problem-specific isolated component encapsulated behind a well-defined API, distributed separately, fitting into a larger distributed system. Any more precise, contextual definition will be, well, context-specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One answer can be found in
[*On Micro-services Architecture* by Dmitry Namiot And Manfred sneps-sneppe](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/265292970_On_Micro-services_Architecture)

> micro-service architecture is an approach to developing an
> application as a set  of  small  independent  services.
> Each  of  the  services  is running   in   its   own   independent
> process.   Services   can communicate  with  some  lightweight
> mechanisms  (usually  it is  something  around  HTTP) .  Such
> services  could be deployed  absolutely  independently.  Also,  the
> centralized management   of   these   services   is   a   completely
> separate service  too.

Sure needs to be put into context but is a good start. And reliable source

Answer (score 0):

### It's not scientific in nature

Code structuring is not scientific, it is intuitive and often relies on analogies with real life and how humans tend to organize among themselves.

> Who defined defined it?

As with a lot of things in the field of software, this was decided by convention. A lot of developers agreed to calling this kind of component a 'service', and the convention had enough popular support to become a standard.

This is no different from how *any* word came into common usage. We just collectively decided that it made sense to use this word in this way.

> Where does one services start and where does it end?

The notion that a service can be definitively bounded clashes with the definition's statement that a service's inner workings are encapsulated and that one service can depend on another.

While we should generally not redefine the responsibility of an established service (cfr OCP), we can gradually enrich its implementation of that responsibility, making it impossible to definitively bound a service in a way that is perpetually correct.

> soa which is hardly 'scientific agreed upon' in the sense it is on the internet.

If you're going to discard any information which was established or distributed online, you're going to run into many, many issues with understanding and defining software development concepts.

By that definition, should you then not also discount any answer you get to this question?

> Surely, abstractly how can we formulate it in a definition?

You're not going to get much further than "behavior-driven component". But due to the vagueness of a component (is it an external runtime? an internal part?), this definition is more tautological than it is helpful.

---

### A service example

It may help to work through this with a practical example. I've said that concepts like these are often analogous to the real world, so let's use a real world example: a service worker. Specifically, a bartender.

A bartender is a service because he serves customers. His responsibility is to provide the drinks that the customers request.

> It logically represents a repeatable business activity with a specified outcome.

The bartender will make the same drink many times during his career, and each drink (of the same type) will be the same, or at least within the expectations of what that drink should be.

> It is self-contained.

The customer does not need to tell the bartender how to do their job. Knowing how to do their job is part of their job, along with actually making the drinks.

> It is a black box for its consumers, meaning the consumer does not have to be aware of the service's inner workings.

The customer does not need to know how to make a strawberry daquiri or a tequila sunrise. The customer also has no say in *how* the bartender makes this drink, e.g. how he crushes the ice cubes. If the bartender prefers to do it manually, use a hammer, or use a blender, that is up to the bartender to decide.

> It may be composed of other services.

The bartender does not make everything from scratch. He does not distill the alcohol, nor does he grow the mint or farm the chickens for their eggs (some cocktails have eggs in them).

The bartender tends to rely on other services: the distiller, the gardener, the poulterer, ...

However, we cannot definitively state what is and what isn't a bartender's job, as long as it is done with the purpose of making a drink for a customer.

- Does the bartender crack his own eggs, or does someone else do it for him?
- Who washes the glasses?
- Who decides how much liquor is used in a given drink?
- When a cocktail requires the use of a hardboiled egg, who boils the egg?

The bartender *could* be the one doing these things, or he could not be. You can't know this for a fact. A bartender working in a nightclub chain might have a very different set of duties compared to someone who runs their own bar, and both of them will be different from a bartender you can hire for your own party where *you* supply the drinks and set the menu. Bartenders working at festivals here have to expect the customer to provide their own drinking receptacle, in a bid to enforce the use of reusable plastic cups.

All of these people are bartenders, they serve drinks to customers, but the precise boundary of their duties are different based on what the surrounding context requires of them.

In short: a service's duties are not objectively, abstractly and definitively boundable. They are contextually decided based on the relevant use case.